# cakephp saveAll not working with associations

Tags: php, cakephp, save, cakephp-2.4

This question may be duplicate. But i have confused with some questions and tutorials.

I try to save an array using following code.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'ques 1',
    'description' => 'lskjdf sldkfj sdlfkjsd flskdjf sldkfjsd',
    'objective' => 'jd ldkjf sldkf sldfj sdlfjdlsfsjfl ds',
    'Question' => array(
        'type' => 'BOOLEAN',
        'body' => 'slkdjfs dflskdf slkfjsiuwsdjkf sd',
        'Answer' => array(
            'body' => 'sd fsldkjfs dddd ddd ddd'
        ),
    ),
);

$this->Questionnaire->create();
$this->Questionnaire->saveAll($data);
```

After run this code questionnaire had save with 3 question but not any answer. only one question has body value.

This is my model class.

Questionnaire.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * Questionnaire Model
 */
class Questionnaire extends AppModel {

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Name is required'
            )
        ),
        'description' => array(

        ),
        'objective' => array(

        ),
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Question' => array(
            'className' => 'Question',
            'foreignKey' => 'questionnairy_id'
        ),
    ); 

}
```

Question.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * Question Model
 */
class Question extends AppModel {

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $validate = array(
        'type' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array(
                    BOOLEAN_ANSWER, 
                    SINGLE_ANSWER, 
                    MULTIPLE_ANSWER, 
                )),
                'message' => 'Invalide type',                
            )
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Question is required'
            )
        ),      
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Questionnaire' => array(
            'className' => 'Questionnaire',
            'foreignKey' => 'questionnaire_id'
        ),
    ); 

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Answer' => array(
            'className' => 'Answer',
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id'
        ),
    ); 

}
```

Answer.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * Answer Model
 */
class Answer extends AppModel {

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $validate = array(
        'body' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Answer is required'
            )
        ),      
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Question' => array(
            'className' => 'Question',
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id'
        ),
    ); 

}
```

I need to know correct way to save this array. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to format your array properly. The `$data` array should look like this:

```
array(
  'Questionnaire' => array(
    'name' => 'Questionnaire 1'
  ),
  'Question' => array(
    array(
      'type' => 'BOOLEAN',
      'body' => 'Is Cake sweet?',
      'Answer' => array(
        array(
          'body' => 'Yes.'
        )
      )
    ),
    array(
      'type' => 'BOOLEAN',
      'body' => 'Does Cake make things easy and fast?',
      'Answer' => array(
        array(
          'body' => 'Yes.'
        )
      )
    ),
  )
);
```

Notice that the Question are in an indexed array (same with Answer). This is because their relationship is hasMany.

The form would look something like this:

```
$this->Form->create('Questionnaire');
$this->Form->input('Questionnaire.name');
$this->Form->input('Question.0.type');
$this->Form->input('Question.0.body');
$this->Form->input('Question.0.Answer.0.body');
$this->Form->input('Question.1.type');
$this->Form->input('Question.1.body');
$this->Form->input('Question.1.Answer.0.body');
$this->Form->end();
```

Lastly, you'll need to tell Cake to keep going when saving:

$this->Questionnaire->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));

Check the book for more info:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Comment: thanks your code. I need only data array. As your array i could save questionnaires and questions. But it not save answer. What is the issue?

Comment: When using plugin models, reference models like this PluginName.ModelClass in Controller::loadModel() call or Controller::$uses variable.